# ExtJs4 - Form defined in javascript multicombo loaded at runtime

Tags: extjs, ext.net

When the form is initially loaded the multicombo on the form correctly reflects  the data that is set up.

However, if I attempt to update the information at runtime, the list of options in the multicombo aren't updated when the form is displayed.

I have them successfully defined as form options, they have a simple 'text' only store. However, I can't seem to find the correct set of properties and method to actually update the multicombo from the C# code as needed.

Comment: Could you please provide some code

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this as well.  You can set the `Ext.net.ListItems` on page-load but they are fickle when it comes to setting them dynamically in code-behind. I now always use a `Ext.net.Store` with any Multicombo or ComboBox that needs to dynamically change.

You can use the Handler events on `Focus` or `BeforeSelect` to reload the list.

```html
<ext:ComboBox ID="ComboBoxTransferGroupMembers" runat="server" FieldLabel="Transfer To"     EmptyText="Group Members" LabelAlign="Top" DisplayField="Name" ValueField="Id" MarginSpec="0 0 5">

  <Listeners>
     <Focus Handler="#{ComboBoxTransferGroupMembers}.store.reload()" />
  </Listeners>

  <Store>
      <ext:Store runat="server" OnReadData="StoreTransferGroupMember_ReadData" ID="StoreXferGroup">
          <Model>
              <ext:Model IDProperty="Id" runat="server">
                  <Fields>
                      <ext:ModelField Name="Name" />
                      <ext:ModelField Name="Id" />
                  </Fields>
              </ext:Model>
          </Model>
          <Parameters>
              <ext:StoreParameter Mode="Raw" Name="Group" Value="#{ComboBoxTransferGroup}.getValue()" />
          </Parameters>

      </ext:Store>
  </Store>
  <DirectEvents>
      <Select OnEvent="ComboBoxTransferGroupMembers_Select">
          <ExtraParams>
              <ext:Parameter Mode="Raw" Name="Group" Value="#{ComboBoxTransferGroup}.getValue()" />
          </ExtraParams>    
      </Select>
  </DirectEvents>

</ext:ComboBox>
```